# How to use far arrow syntax when creating a Prototype?

Tags: javascript

If I want to a create  prototype on `String`, how can I do so with the ES6 fat arrow syntax and return the string.  If I do :

```
String.prototype.foo = () => {
   return this
}
```

..it returns the Window object, which makes sense since `this` is binded with the fat arrow.
How exactly would I return `this`?

Comment: You can't. Don't use arrow functions if you need to capture the calling context.

Comment: thank you, makes sense

Comment: Also don't pollute global namespaces. String already has a prototype, and things work best if you leave all built-ins alone.